# Suppose G is a group and N and M are normal subgroups of G. True or false: if G/N and G/M are isomorphic, then N and M are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If true, prove it. If false, give a counterexample.

My inclination is that this is true. Because if G/N and G/M are isomorphic, N and M have the same order. Moreover, each element of G/N corresponds to an element of the same order in G/M, so the same should be between the normal subgroups N and M. Am I missing some counterexample that would prove this wrong? And if it's true, how would I get this proof started?

Comment: This question must have been asked already 8342450423 times...but I can't find one of the almost infinite examples of it!

Comment: Your intuition there is a good start, but note that that only holds when $G$ is finite. What happens when you have an infinite group?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the group is finite or not. The groups $G/N$ and $G/M$ have "forgotten" the elements of $N$ and $M$ and all of their group structure; any isomorphism $G/N\cong G/M$ should not be expected to "know" much of anything about $N$ or $M$ or any structural relations between them, in particular if they are isomorphic or not.

Comment: @Mik: "N and M have the same order"...but are groups of the same order always isomorphic? I don't think so, consider the cyclic group of order $4$ and the Klein $4$-group.

Answer (score 2):

Consider subgroups of order $4$ in the group $(\mathbb Z/4)\times(\mathbb Z/2)$.

Comment: So, $(1+\mathbb{Z})\times(1+\mathbb{Z})$ , $(3+\mathbb{Z})\times(1+\mathbb{Z})$ , $(1+\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z})$ and $(3+\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z})$ are the subgroups of order $4$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/4)\times(\mathbb{Z}/2)$. So I show that two of these are not isomorphic to one another?

Comment: by my calculations each of the subgroups generated by these elements have elements of order 1, 2, 4, and 4. How can I show that there aren't isomorphic?

Comment: @Mik Notice that some but not all of the subgroups of order 4 are cyclic.